# Evaluation of a rational function infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been wanting to evaluate the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{36}{\left(5n^2+12n+6\right)^2}$$

According to Wikipedia, one can use the digamma function to evaluate infinite series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Evaluation_of_sums_of_rational_functions

I've tried decomposing my fraction into the form $$\frac{36}{\left(5n^2+12n+6\right)^2}=\frac{\frac{36}{25}}{\left(\left(n-\frac{-6+\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)\left(n-\frac{-6-\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)\right)^2}=\frac{A}{\left(n-\frac{-6+\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)^{2}}+\frac{B}{\left(n-\frac{-6-\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)^{2}}$$

where A and B are constants. However, the result I got, which was:
$$=\frac{\frac{72-17\sqrt{6}}{100}}{\left(n+\frac{6-\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)^{2}}+\frac{\frac{72+17\sqrt{6}}{100}}{\left(n+\frac{6+\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)^{2}}$$

doesn't seem to match my original expression when I graphed it.
Here's how I solved for A and B:

$$\frac{A}{\left(n-\frac{-6+\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)^{2}}+\frac{B}{\left(n-\frac{-6-\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)^{2}}=\frac{36}{\left(5n^{2}+12n+6\right)^{2}}$$
$$\implies\frac{A\left(n+\frac{6+\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)^{2}+B\left(n+\frac{6-\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)^{2}}{\left(n+\frac{6-\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)^{2}\left(n+\frac{6+\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)^{2}}=\frac{36}{\left(5n^{2}+12n+6\right)^{2}}$$
$$\implies A\left(n+\frac{6+\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)^{2}+B\left(n+\frac{6-\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)^{2}=36$$

Then I proceeded by setting all terms including $n$ equal to zero and the constants equal to 36.
I think it's because when a fraction with quadratic denominators is being decomposed, the resulting numerators have degree 1, but in this case I set A and B to be equal to a degree 0 expression.

I now have no idea how to continue, because partial fractions doesn't seem to work here. Or is there another way I can proceed?

Here's the result WolframAlpha gave me:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{36}{\left(5n^2+12n+6\right)^2}=\frac{1}{4} \left(6 \left(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{6}{5}-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)+\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{5} \left(\sqrt{6}+6\right)\right)\right)+5
\sqrt{6} \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{6}{5}-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{5}\right)-5 \sqrt{6} \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{5} \left(\sqrt{6}+6\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: The partial fraction decomposition of $\dfrac{1}{(n-a)^2(n-b)^2}$ is of the form $$ \frac{A}{n-a} + \frac{B}{(n-a)^2}+\frac{C}{n-b} + \frac{D}{(n-b)^2}$$

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. But how do I find the values for those constants?